# how can two sidemenus be used in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone, side-menu

I want to add sidemenus at both left and right side.How can it be done in codenameone ?

> getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(new Command(" Menu 1 "));

I can left sidemenu by using above code and i want to add that on right also.

Answer (score 0):

The `Toolbar` class no longer supports the right side menu. This functionality has always been problematic and was deprecated a while back. We might re-introduce it with the [new "on top" side menu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sidemenu-on-top.html) rewrite but right now that functionality is too new.